# System.hashCode still broken for Id

Tags: apex, map, set, hashcode

Five years ago there was [System.hashCode broken on Id properties of SObjects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82930/system-hashcode-broken-on-id-properties-of-sobjects) and I've just run into it again today. You can see the problem by running this test case:

```
@IsTest
static void hashCodeForId() {

    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Acme');
    insert a;

    System.assertEquals(
        System.hashCode((String) a.Id),
        System.hashCode((String) a.Id)
    );                                  // OK

    System.assertEquals(
        System.hashCode(a.Id),
        System.hashCode(a.Id)
    );                                  // Fails
}
```

It hurts when you build your own class that implements `equals`/`hashCode` that e.g. combines several properties where at least one is an `Id`. Also extra painful because when debugging is turned on `hashCode` isn't called at all in set/map logic so the problem is hidden.

The work-around is to turn the Ids into strings as shown in the above test. So the only question I have is whether laughing or crying is the appropriate response to this...

Comment: Definitely crying. That said, I'd be happy to open the third bug report in 30 days, I'm going for a record .

Comment: Yes please. Don't want to be posting this again in another 5 years...

Comment: Oh, the [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YQ0AAM) has been updated this year, is in review. No need for another case, but I will ping someone to see if we can get even a tentative update.

Comment: I'm with the tear-shedders on this one.

Comment: There is something freaky about putting `System.debug(System.hashCode(a.Id));` in a loop and watching it repeatedly output different hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per Chris Peterson](https://twitter.com/ca_peterson/status/1334269513638924288):

> Known. Fixed in next release. Doesn't impact apex collection correctness since they use magic to use a "proper" hashCode value thankfully.

Obviously, #SafeHarbor, but it should be fixed soon enough.

Comment: Will that also add `hashCode()` as a proper method on `Id`?

Comment: @Frans No, it doesn't add a new method. Use System.hashCode to get the value.

Comment: Really strange that `String` has a `hashCode()` method where `Id` does not...